# Why does this regex only return the last match?

Tags: python, regex

I don't understand why this regex only returns the last match:

```
import re
text = """
Chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken.

#=================
# @title   Chicken
# @author  Me
#=================
Chicken chicken chicken.
"""

rx = r"#=+\n(?:#\s*@(\w+)\s+(.*)\n)+#=+"
for match in re.finditer( rx, text ):
    print match.groups()

# Output:
# ('author', 'Me')
```

I would expect this regex to return `[ ('title', 'Chicken'), ('author', 'Me') ]`, but it seems to only return the last match. This does not change if I set the flag `re.M` (multiline), and the flag `re.DOTALL` is not what I intend here.

For clarity, you can [visualise the regex here](https://regexper.com/#%23%3D%2B%5Cn(%3F%3A%23%5Cs*%40(%5Cw%2B)%5Cs%2B(.*)%5Cn)%2B%23%3D%2B), it seems to be what I intended, namely:

- From the first comment line `#===...`
- Find and capture the next lines with the format `# @(word) (anything)`

Comment: The regex does not return overlapping matches.

Comment: @DietrichEpp But the non-capturing group (`(?: ...)`) is not overlapping here, is it?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060659/python-regexes-how-to-access-multiple-matches-of-a-group

Comment: Try: `rx = r"(?:#\s*@(\w+)\s+(.*?)\n)"`

Comment: The grouping doesn't matter--what matters is the whole regex. Because the regex starts with `#=\n` and ends with `#=\n`, it can only match once between the `#==` and `#==` lines.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Well, I understand the problem, but does that mean I cannot do this with regexes? The suggestion of @coldspeed does not achieve the same thing; is there a way to enforce the constraint that matching lines should be just below the line `#===`?

Comment: Right, apparently this is a [known issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue7132) for which a fix has been deemed unnecessary.

Comment: I managed to do it with two regexes instead. The first one  `rx1 = r"#=+(.*?)#=+"` used with the flag `re.DOTALL` extracts the blocks of comments fenced by `#==` lines. The second one `rx2 = r"(?:#\s*@(\w+)\s+(.+))"` matches individual lines within each block.

Comment: Actually, I think the comment by @n611x007 in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4963691/472610) is a "better" duplicate.