# Converting test string match result to match group in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on Python about Regex Data. Here example of my data:

```
Name: Ahmet Tugra Doger 
University: Arel University

Name: Cagatay Yucelen 
University: Istanbul Technical University
```

Okay so, I want to group all name, universities, then change their name in the same time. And for this  I use this code:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'Name: (?<NewName>.*)\nUniversity.*:(?  
<NewUniversity>\n*)')

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:      
contents = f.read()       

matches = pattern.finditer(contents)  

for match in matches:              
    print(match.group(0))
```

So after a while I get an error but my expected output result is:

```
NewName: Ahmet Tugra Doger 
NewUniversity: Arel University

NewName: Cagatay Yucelen 
NewUniversity: Istanbul Technical University
```

So, Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like https://regex101.com/ to validate test your regex?

Comment: Your second capture group is not closed, the correct regex should look more like `Name: (?P<NewName>.*)\nUniversity: (?P<NewUniversity>.*)\n`

Comment: Once you have validated your regex, you can use the `.captures` method of the regex module as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30202102/3130972

Comment: error('unknown extension ?<N at position 7',) --> This is my error massage